# how to see simbols in cordova utf-8

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

how can i correct this problem with simbols in cordova?
i have already put this tag in my head project:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--
        Personalice la directiva de seguridad de contenido en la etiqueta meta como sea necesario. Agregue "unsafe-inline" a default-src para permitir JavaScript insertado.
        Para obtener m�s detalles, consulte http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>CcoMovil2017Ult</title>
    <!-- Referencias de CCOMovil -->
    <link href="kendo/src/styles/mobile/kendo.mobile.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you are opening the source file with an encoding different than utf8. Or maybe it was opened and saved with another encoding in the past. Check the encoding used by your editor

Comment: where do i check that?

Comment: Which editor do you use? Usually is under file -> encoding, in Visual Studio is under settings